# Janrain server side response to Android app

Tags: php, android, janrain

[Here's](https://rpxnow.com/docs/android#) the documentation on how to implement Janrain engine in Android.

Example of server side response is [here](https://rpxnow.com/docs/android#token_url).

Quote: "As necessary create and return access tokens or session cookies in your endpoint's response.", I don't want to save data on session or cookies, I want to get just plain text to my app as response.

How can I do this?

Also I work with php, I don't really get ruby example.

Answer (score 0):

There is some sample PHP code at https://github.com/janrain/Janrain-Sample-Code/blob/master/php/rpx-token-url.php that returns a block of JSON. You could customize this code to return the plain text response you're looking for.